# Implementing HTML Element Pagination with Java iText Library

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, itext7

I am working on an iText report where I need to transfer HTML content to another page in a PDF document when it overflows an iText rectangle. The HTML code is obtained from a `contenteditable` div and includes various elements such as text and images.

I'm adding html to report using HtmlConverter but i have no idea how to handle overflow of this rectangle.

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4;
PdfDocument pdfBackground = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(PDF));
PdfPage backgroundPage = pdfBackground.getFirstPage();
Document document = new Document(pdf, pageSize);
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
        
        
pdf.addPage(backgroundPage.copyTo(pdf)); // adding background using another pdf
Rectangle mainContent = new Rectangle(70, 120, 510, 600);
Canvas rCanvas = new Canvas(pdf.getLastPage() ,mainContent);
addHtml(HtmlConverter.convertToElements("<p>Html code here<p>", properties), rCanvas);
```

Is there a way to calculate the size of content within a rectangle? Alternatively, do you have any other suggestions for addressing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using this code.

```
    private static float calculateContentHeight(Canvas canvas, List<IElement> elements, float maxWidth) {
        float totalHeight = 0;

        for (IElement element : elements) {
            LayoutResult result = ((IBlockElement) element).createRendererSubTree().setParent(canvas.getRenderer())
                    .layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, new Rectangle(maxWidth, 10000))));
            totalHeight += result.getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getHeight();
        }

        return totalHeight;
    }
```